# Would an object with mass and acceleration leave a black hole easily with out getting stuck?

Tags: black-holes, speed-of-light

Considering an object such as a rocket with enough fuel.

The black hole being between the earth's size and the sun's size.

Have the rocket travel towards the black hole and threw its event horizon with constant forward acceleration and not collide with any objects.

This would make the rocket travel faster than the speed of light as the speed of light is constant and the rocket accelerating from fuel.

Would not the rocket always come out the other side due to the momentum of mass, & the acceleration of the rocket?

Comment: As soon as the rocket crosses the event horizon, its future is toward the singularity.

Comment: Its worth remembering that relativistic physics was invented because simple and clear thinking like the thought experiment above started yielding peculiar results when we actually experimented on it -- the actual results did not line up with the classical physics predictions.  Black holes are the epitome of relativistic physics.

Comment: *"constant forward acceleration"* - according to whom? Are you stipulating that the spacecraft has constant proper acceleration (acceleration as measured by an accelerometer on the spacecraft)? If so, such a spacecraft can never exceed the speed of light (this has been discussed many times before here). If not, then to what observer does the spacecraft have constant forward acceleration?

Comment: I think there is a good question here. Suppose the rocket turns off its motor so it just coasts. Then why wouldn't it fall in the horizon, past the singularity and out the other side? That's not a trivial question to answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I honestly don't understand the "non-mainstream physics" close votes but maybe I've missed something. Regardless, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @JohnRennie Unless I'm mistaken, it's because all future trajectories end at the singularity once the horizon is crossed.

Comment: Well there are two things that are not immediately obvious to the non-GR head. Firstly why do all trajectories reach the singularity, and secondly why can't they go through the singularity and out the other side? Both of these are interesting and not obvious issues.

Answer (score 2):

"Constant forward acceleration" past the speed of light is impossible. In classical mechanics, it requires more energy to accelerate ($\dot{E} = mv\dot{v}$) the faster you move, but in special relativity, your total energy $E=\gamma mc^{2}$, where $\gamma \rightarrow \infty$ as you approach the speed of light. Another way to put it, is that you need infinite energy to reach the speed of light, due to special relativity.

Jeanbaptiste Roux also makes the excellent point that the future is toward the singularity--at whatever speed, once you cross the event horizon, there is no coming back. This is because time and space are bent around a black hole so that the future (time) actually points in a spatial direction (towards the center of the singularity).

Comment: The momentum of the rocket would cancel out the effects of the singularity, along with centrifugal force. The gravity of the black hole would be able to pull you are greater the speed of light, and the momentum would pull you out to a region where your acceleration would finish the job.

Comment: In general relativity gravity is no longer just a force, so you cannot balance it with centrifugal force. Moreover, since energy is mass, the faster you go, the more mass you have, so if you did think of gravity as a force, it would become stronger the faster you went. You would never be able to defeat gravity once you are inside the event horizon.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to apply classical physics to a situation that does not follow classical laws.

- The rocket ship, using the concept of a force applied by the burning of fuel will not cause the rocket to move faster than c upon crossing the event horizon because the energy content of the rocket will increase to an infinite amount. What actually occurs inside the event horizon is difficult to determine and remains largely speculative (unknown).
- Using a classical concept your are attempting to argue that the gravitational potential energy is converted to kinetic energy as the object falls toward a gravitating mass and that this same kinetic energy can be converted to gravitational potential energy as the object leaves the other side (assuming no collision occurred).  Therefore, you suggest it should be possible to exit the event horizon from the other side.
- The problem with this reasoning is that classical concepts only work well in areas where the spacetime is very close to being flat.  This closely resembles the Euclidean geometry that we use in everyday life.  But, strong gravitational influences (such as black holes) curve both space and spacetime in a significant way.  This means that the rules that apply to Euclidean space cannot be applied (with any success) near a black hole and certainly do not apply within the event horizon of  the black hole.